# Understanding who is consuming Platform Events, and how much, is it possible?

Tags: limits, streaming-api, subscriber, platform-event, cometd

When a platform event is fired, it is consumed from whichever client is subscribed to its specific channel.

If a single event is fired and consumed by 5 consumers, it will count 5 against the Daily Limit, which is 25k.

Salesforce provides who is subscribed to a Platform event since this subscription is performed with a Process Builder or an Apex Trigger. There is no way, as far as I know, to know/understang who from outside Salesforce, for example CometD clients, is subscribed.

Does anyone know if this is by any chance possible?

Comment: there is an active discussion of this on the Salesforce Success Community for Platform Events

Comment: @cropredy do you have a link to that discussion?

Comment: @Folkert - here's the link - https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A0000004gjg lot's of good stuff here